# Detect uncorrelative values in column series in R

Tags: r, series

I hope you can help again me with this issue regarding correlative values from columns in R. I have a big dataframe, to simplify it, it look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(radius = c (1,2,3,4,5,2,3,5,6,1,2,1,2,3,6,7,2,3,4,2,3,5,6))
df$num <- c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7)
df
```

The column `num` has values (for example 1 and 5) and column `radius` depends on this column. So, for `num ==1`, we have radius values from 1 to 4, these are correlative. that is perfect!

However, for `num ==5`, we have radius values 1 to 7, but there is no value 4 (nor 5). I want to detect this break in the series and create another column which states where does this break happens.

Moreover, if the break happens at value 4, also states that the following rows should be changed (of the same `num`). Therefore, value 6 and 7 should be detected too.

The outcome should look like this:

Where were 1 means "in" and 2 means "out"

```
df$outcome <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2)
df
```

thanks a lot!